# Why am I unable to convert Datetime to the required format

Tags: c#, datetime

This is the requirement

I am having my field declared in my class file as Datetime.

I am taking a string and i would like to convert it to Datetime as my filed in my class is in date time

I always pass it as

```
    String date="9999-12-31 00:00:00"
```

I would like to convert this to date time so that the output format should be the same as the given string

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear in terms of whether "9999-12-31" is your intended *input* or *output*. Please take a little time to clarify your question - ideally with a complete sample program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It is the input which i am giving as string

Comment: I'm confused... "9999-12-31" **isn't** "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"...

Comment: Ya that was just given as 9999-12-31

Comment: @Dorababu: So if that's the input, why are you trying to *parse* it as if it had a time?

Comment: I added time now please check

Comment: @Dorababu: Well that's *still* not in the format that you've specified. And which is your *real* input? If your real input contained the time to start with, why didn't you give that in your question?

Comment: You are mixing 24h format with AM/PM, you know?

Comment: And now the question has changed yet again, and is still unclear. *Please* read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Make sure you are clear in your mind what your input is and your desired output, then express both clearly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, you're trying to *parse* "9999-12-31" with a format string of "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" - which it doesn't comply to, as it has no time.

EDIT: Okay, so you've now changed the input to "9999-12-31 21:34 PM" which *still* isn't in the appropriate format - there's no T, no seconds, and there's an am/pm designator. Why are you not using a format string which actually matches your input?

But if "9999-12-31" is the *input*, what *output* are you expecting?

Comment: Jon i am giving as a string but my field in my layer is Datetime format so i need to be in datetime format so that the output should be "9999-12-31 00:00:00"

Comment: @Dorababu: So why were you trying to format it without the time? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Dorababu: Hang on - you've changed the question *again*, so that supposedly your *input* is "9999-12-31 00:00:00" - but that's also what you want your *output* to be. What on earth is going on? What is *really* your input, and what do you *really* want out of it? This is like drawing blood from a stone.

Comment: @Dorababu: Your question *still* isn't clear. Are you expecting that a `DateTime` itself has a format? It doesn't. It's just the date and time; it doesn't know what format you want to use - you have to supply that when you call `ToString`. I strongly suggest you create a *short but complete* program which demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: I know datetime it self ha no format but i would like to pass my date as 9999-12-31 00:00:00 to the value oEmployee.EndDate in my class file

Comment: @Dorbabu: Then just parse it to a `DateTime` and use `DateTime.Date` to truncate it to midnight.

Comment: Ok but i am getting date+time as 12:00:00:AM i need it to be as 00:00:00 how can i

Comment: @Dorababu: You just said you understood that the DateTime had no particular format... and yet now you're complaining that it's got the *wrong* format. If you want to convert it to a string in a particular format, call ToString and supply that format. You do understand that 12:00:00:00AM and 00:00:00 represent the same time, don't you? And that the date and time are all the information present in the `DateTime`?

Comment: if i am applying as per you said like suppose i declared my variable as datetime dt dt=dt.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd") i am getting an error an error as conversion error if i again use convert.todatetime before that it is working why

Comment: @Dorababu: Because you're trying to assign a *string* value to a DateTime variable! Only convert it to a string when you *need* it as a string.

Comment: But the final output should be in Datetime format not in string format

Comment: @Dorababu: Then why do you care what the *text* rendition of the value is? You've got the right value, however it's displayed. You *still* seem to be missing the point that a DateTime doesn't have an inherent format. If I told you to meet me at 3pm, that would be the same as telling you 15:00 hours, wouldn't it? They're different representations of the *same time*. So it is with `DateTime` values. Ignore the format the debugger happens to show the value in - *the DateTime value itself has no particular format*. You want midnight at the start of December 31st 9999; you've got it.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

to

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This will convert `9999-12-31 21:34 PM` to `9999-12-31` (if using `dt.ToString("yyy-MM-dd")`).

Note that this DateTime will contain the hours/minutes etc. If you want to remove the hours/minutes from the DateTime, use something like this:

```
 dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 0, 0, 0, dt.Kind);
```

If you specify an format to [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), then your input string has to have exactly this format to be convertet to a DateTime. You can use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: One more thing while returning the dt i am still able to see 12/31/9999 9:34:00 PM while passing instead of the one i required can but if i have a look in quick watch i can see what i required why is this happening

Comment: Because the DateTime contains still the hours/minutes. You are just returning a string displaying the DateTime formatted with "yyyy-MM-dd". If you want to return the DateTime stripped off the hours/minutes, you have to create a new DateTime with hours/minutes etc. set to 0. I have updated my answer.

Comment: But still i am able to see time in dt

Comment: @Dorababu: A `DateTime` will always have a notional time in, even if it's midnight. It is a *DateTime* after all.

Comment: @Dorababu: You still haven't made it clear what output you want. If you only need a string, then by the time you've formatted `dt` using `yyyy-MM-dd` as a format string, why do you care that `dt` itself contains a time? The string won't.

Comment: The out put i need should be in the format yyyy-MM-dd as i am having my field as Datetime i would like to convert the given string to date format while formatting i would like the output should be in the format yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: @Dorababu: You've just said in another comment that you want an output of "9999-12-31 00:00:00" which is *not* in yyyy-MM-dd format. I give up - either you don't know what you want, or you can't be bothered to express yourself clearly. I see no point in continuing to try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
    strDate, 
    "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt", 
    DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, 
    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: One more thing while returning the dt i am still able to see 12/31/9999 9:34:00 PM while passing instead of the one i required can but if i have a look in quick watch i can see what i required why is this happening